# How to add a system call with a suitable wrapper function in glibc

Tags: glibc

I added a hello_world system call to linux 4.4.2 by using https://tssurya.wordpress.com/2014/08/19/adding-a-hello-world-system-call-to-linux-kernel-3-16-0/.But it can only be called by using its system call number 
such as :-

```
long int a = syscall(326);
```

where 326 is the system call number.
Now i want to call the the same system call function with a wrapper function such as `hello_world()` with out specifying the system call number.Can anybody suggest me the way to do so by using glibc ?.Thanks in advance

Comment: How is glibc related?

Comment: i need to create an abstraction over the usage of system call number. i.e., create a higher level function like hello_world() in place of calling with a system call number. Can i use glibc for this?

Answer (score 0):

you will need to update your kernel headers (e.g. the `/usr/include/asm*/*unistd*.h` that matches your arch) to have a symbol `__NR_hello_world` define.  then you can build glibc against those headers.

the easiest way to get glibc to generate a symbol is to edit a file that matches your arch like `sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/syscalls.list`.  glibc uses that to dynamically generate a list of symbols.

make sure to also update `sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/Versions` so the symbol is exported.

all that said, using `syscall(326)` is the best answer, especially when you just want to do kernel hacking.  messing with glibc is uncommon.